# How to Delete patern from multiple files

Tags: linux, bash, centos

I've a data files with information like this :

```
977.txt:ahdcompany@yemen.net.ye
977.txt:ahemdrasheed@yemen.nrt.ye
980.txt:ahmedmohammed@y.ne.ye
982.txt:qfofs@yemen.net.ye
985.txt:agencysabaship@y.net.ye
987.txt:aghani@y.net.ye
987.txt:agk46@india.yellowpages.net.com
991.txt:aige_yemen@y.net.ye
991.txt:aige_yemen@y.net.ye
991.txt:aihaidechenmo@163.yeah.net
994.txt:qichange@163.yeah.net
995.txt:aina@email.yes
999.txt:aisco@y.net.ye
```

i want to remove everything before :
how can i do that for all files in directory ( Linux ).

i've tried this, and it's working but i'm unable to use it with multiple files:

```
grep -o - '[[:alnum:]+\._\-]*@[[:alnum:]+\._\-]*' file.txt
```

Comment: Yes , i've tried grep grep -o - '[[:alnum:]+\.\_\-]*@[[:alnum:]+\.\_\-]*' file.txt and it's working but i'm unable to use it with multiple files

Comment: use `grep -h` so that the file names are not displayed

Comment: Did you use `grep` to create the file? If so, consider using `grep -h` to avoid prefixing the matches with the filename. You then wouldn't need to post-process it.

Answer (score 1):

Another `sed` solution.

```
$ sed -n 's/[^:]*\://p' infile
ahdcompany@yemen.net.ye
ahemdrasheed@yemen.nrt.ye
ahmedmohammed@y.ne.ye
qfofs@yemen.net.ye
agencysabaship@y.net.ye
aghani@y.net.ye
agk46@india.yellowpages.net.com
aige_yemen@y.net.ye
aige_yemen@y.net.ye
aihaidechenmo@163.yeah.net
qichange@163.yeah.net
aina@email.yes
aisco@y.net.ye
$
```

This can easily be extended to do in-place editing using the `-i` option, and to recursively edit files in a directory tree using `find`

Answer (score 0):

To delete the leading part in all you files in a single directory:

```
sed -i -r 's/^[0-9]+\.txt://' *
```

Test on a copy of a few files first.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how much files is involve or how deep the directory goes, you might hit some errors but for small set of files this should work with ed.

```
 printf '%s\n' 'g/^.*:\(.*\)/s//\1/' w q | ed -s *
```